# I want to get a formula to calculate pokemon damage

Tags: javascript, formula, algebra

My problem is that I want the result of the total damage to be based on the maximum life of my entity and his level (1-100), I mean that if the damage is 70, and the maximum life of the victim is 70, that a certain percentage be lowered without using floats or percentages.

Those are stats that im trying to use.

```
damagerDamage = 45
entityLevel = 1
maxEntityHealth = 45
```

This is the formula that ive been using.
`totalResult = maxEntityHealth * damagerDamage / entityLevel`

Its should be less, since im using the max Health in the formula, it goes crazy, so yeah i dont know what to do. Can anyone help me?

The problems results:

```
maxEntity: 45
totalResult: 2025
```

Comment: Hello @Tinajero, welcome to Stack Overflow! If you're looking for the exact formula used within the Pokémon games to calculate damage dealt, you should go here: https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Damage#Damage_calculation

Comment: Oh, this is a special case lol, those cant help me :(

Comment: Your description is a little bit confusing. Maybe adding some example data inputs/outputs could demonstrate what you want to achieve.

Comment: What does the damage reduction depend on? The defending entity's level? If what you are asking is "How to scale `damageTaken` from `0` to `maxDamage` that reduces with increasing `entityLevel` which can go from `1` to `maxEntityLevel`?", one way to do that is `maxDamage * (1 - entityLevel / maxEntityLevel)`. (may need tweaks to handle the boundaries)

Giving examples in a tabular format with example values may help you visualise the problem better and make it easier to help you with exactly what you need :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something you are looking for.

```
damagerDamage = 45
entityLevel = 1
maxEntityHealth = 45

//Calculate the percentage of maxEntityHealth based on damagerDamage
percentageOfMaxHealth = damagerDamage / maxEntityHealth

//Apply the reduction based on entityLevel
reducedDamage = percentageOfMaxHealth * (100 - entityLevel)

//Round down the result to the nearest integer
totalResult = int(reducedDamage)

console.log("maxEntity:", maxEntityHealth)
console.log("totalResult:", totalResult)
```

Comment: TYSM, thats what i was looking for!